# Image link in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to make an image link rather than a text link in JavaScript. I'm very new to JavaScript and I just can't figure out why what I've done isn't working! It would work in HTML.

This works (text link 'close [x]'):

```
    closeLinkString = "<div class='close'><a href='#' id='close-link' onclick=\"Megadropdowns.closeDropDown(); return false;\">close [x]</a></div>", // this is the close button
```

But for some reason this doesn't:

```
    closeLinkString = "<div class='close'><a href='#' id='close-link' onclick=\"Megadropdowns.closeDropDown(); return false;\"><img src="/images/loading.gif"></a></div>", // this is the close button
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 7):

As you can see from SO's syntax highlighting, you need to escape the `"` in the image tag by using `\"` instead:

```
closeLinkString = "<div class='close'><a href='#' id='close-link' onclick=\"Megadropdowns.closeDropDown(); return false;\"><img src=\"/images/loading.gif\"></a></div>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Any editor with basic colour coding, even your post on this site, would show you immediately that you didn't escape the quotes in the image.